# How to find average of two numbers that wrap around?

Tags: algorithm, math, integer, average, integer-arithmetic

I have an `int` that represents numbers in the range [0, 8[ that wraps around:

```
       2      
  1         3


0             4


  7         5
       6
```

Now I need to find the average of two numbers like this, so that for example the average of 7 and 0 would be 7.5, the average of 7 and 2 would be 0.5, the average of 0 and 4 would be 2 or 6, etc.

I found [this ("How do you calculate the average of a set of angles?")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491738/3425536) related question, but it's about angles and I don't see how it could help here. There's also ["How to subtract two unsigned ints with wrap around or overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2061245/3425536) but it's about subtracting, and not about finding an average. Any pointers?

I also have a wrap function, if that can be utilized here somehow:

```
template <class type>
inline type Wrap(type Value, type Minimum, type Maximum)
{
  Value = ((Value - Minimum) % (Maximum + 1 - Minimum));
  return (Value >= 0 ? Minimum : Maximum + 1) + Value;
}
```

**Edit:** Trying to define the rules more formally:

If `abs(a - b) <= 4` then `avg = (a + b) / 2.`.
Otherwise, `avg = (a + b) / 2. + 4; if (avg >= 8) avg -= 8;`.

Comment: What should the avarage of `0` and `4` be? `2` or `6`?

Comment: @o11c Doesn't matter.

Comment: @zenith it should matter because we don't know if it should be 2 or 6, or 0 or 4...

Comment: @AlexYan Rewording: It doesn't _need_ to be either one. Both of them are acceptable.

Comment: Why can't you just use those formulas to implement this? Looks straight forward enough.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes now that I realized what the formulas are, looks like I could...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first return expression is what you're after:

```py
def av(a,b):
    mi = min(a,b)
    ma = max(a,b)
    if ma - mi > 4:
        return (((mi + 8) + ma) / 2.) % 8
    else:
        return (mi+ma)/2.
```

mi is the minimum of the two; ma is the max.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the answer you [cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491738/how-do-you-calculate-the-average-of-a-set-of-angles) by converting your numbers to angles first:

1. Convert your numbers to angles.

   ```
   angle_a = a * pi / 4
   angle_b = b * pi / 4
   ```
2. Compute unit vectors for each angle

   ```
   unit_a
   unit_b
   ```
3. Compute unit vectors average

   ```
   unit_average = (unit_a + unit_b) / 2
   ```
4. Compute angle of unit_average

   ```
   angle_average
   ```
5. Convert angle_average to number

   ```
   number_average = angle_average * 4 / pi
   ```

then **number_average** is our answer

Answer (score 1):

Crude but effective:

```c
float foo(int a, int b)
{
  int c;
  if(a>b)
    {
      c=a;
      a=b;
      b=c;
    }

  if( b-a > 3)
    {
      c=a+8;
      a=b;
      b=c;
    }

  float f = 0.5*(a+b);
  if(f>7.6)
    f-=8.0;
  return(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
float wAvg(int m, int n)
{
    int minimum = min(m, n);
    int maximum = max(m, n);

    int d1 = minimum + 8 - maximum; // difference between m and n
                                    // when wrapped around
    int d2 = max - min;             // normal difference

    float avg = 0.0f;

    if (d1 < d2)    // if wrapped around distance is shorter than normal distance
    {
        avg = d1 / 2.0f + maximum;

        if (avg >= 8.0f)
            avg -= 8.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        avg = (m + n) / 2.0f;
    }

    return avg;
}
```

I think this might work

Answer (score 1):

After seeing @Beta's "crude" answer, just for fun :) :

```c
float wAvg(int m, int n)
{
    static float results[8][8] =
    {
        {0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f, 2.0f, 6.5f, 7.0f, 7.5f},
        {0.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f, 2.0f, 2.5f, 3.0f, 7.5f, 0.0f},
        {1.0f, 1.5f, 2.0f, 2.5f, 3.0f, 3.5f, 4.0f, 0.5f},
        {1.5f, 2.0f, 2.5f, 3.0f, 3.5f, 4.0f, 4.5f, 5.0f},
        {2.0f, 2.5f, 3.0f, 3.5f, 4.0f, 4.5f, 5.0f, 5.5f},
        {6.5f, 3.0f, 3.5f, 4.0f, 4.5f, 5.0f, 5.5f, 6.0f},
        {7.0f, 7.5f, 4.0f, 4.5f, 5.0f, 5.5f, 6.0f, 6.5f},
        {7.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 5.0f, 5.5f, 6.0f, 6.5f, 7.0f}
    };

    return results[m % 8][n % 8];
}
```

Comment: since the table is symmetric about the diagonal axis, you can just store half the table to save memory

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the following would work (in the same way it does for angles):

```js
function meanWrappingValue(values: Array<number>, range: number): number {
    return meanAngle(values.map(value => value * (Math.PI * 2) / range)) / (Math.PI * 2) * range;
}

function meanAngle(angles: Array<number>): number {
    let sinSum = angles.reduce((sum, cur) => sum + Math.sin(cur), 0);
    let cosSum = angles.reduce((sum, cur) => sum + Math.cos(cur), 0);
    return normalizeAngle(Math.atan2(sinSum / angles.length, cosSum / angles.length));
}

function normalizeAngle(angle: number): number {
    let range = Math.PI * 2;
    return ((angle % range) + range) % range;
}
```

In your case it would be:

```
let result = meanWrappingValue([7, 2], 8);
console.log(result); // => 0.5
```